# Link docker-compose container to an exist running container

Tags: mongodb, containers, docker-compose, external-links

I'm trying to run a docker-compose with an exist mongodb container.

In my docker-compose I made this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    external_links:
      - mongo
volumes:
  data:
    external: true
```

I'm running mongodb with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v /docker/mongo/data:/data/db --name mongo mongo
```

In normal links in docker-compose, when you run `curl mongo`, I can connect the mongodb. But I want to use the same mongodb for two different projects.

Using `external_links`, if I cannot connect mongodb. How can I use external_links in correct way?

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using version 2 of docker-compose, which means linking is handled differently than in older versions. All services started using `docker-compose up` will be part of a common network. You can specify that network, or docker-compose will create it automatically for you. In order to link to your mongodb container, you need to pass in the `--network` flag when you start it.

References:

- Note about external links in version 2:
  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/externallinks
- How to
  specify your network in docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/networks
- How to
  specify your network in `docker run`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/connect-a-container-to-a-network---network

Comment: Thanks for this. Works like a charm here.